# How to detect an Android device the right way?

Tags: android, browser-detection, virtual-keyboard

I have a problem where I need to detect whether a web page is running on an Android browser. The use case is that the page needs to be adjusted in relation to the presence of the virtual keyboard.

The reason that I need to know if the user is on an Android device is because on the Android, unlike an iOS device, the viewport height setting is modified by the presence of the keyboard to reflect the remaining space this is visible. On an iOS device, you have to set up an educated guess based on knowing (about) how much space on the screen the virtual keyboard takes up.

So I need to be able to know how to calculate the viewport height because it's different unfortunately for these different operating system contexts. Does anyone have any ideas about how this should be done? I know that browser sniffing is not advisable, so what is one to do in a case like this? Ideas anyone? Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Are you writing html, or css, or what? I have my Apache web server detect the type of device, then rewrite the url to direct users to different pages. I guess that's not what you want.

Comment: No, this is on the client side. The page needs to make some adjustments to its layout when the virtual keyboard is open. It's kind of a mess. The root problem is that there's no way to know the amount of space that the virtual keyboard is using up, and the consequences of the virtual keyboard opening differs across browsers and devices. It's a mess. Incidentally, isn't it sort of a bad idea to do browser sniffing on the server?

Comment: Use reactive layout with [@media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). Media query allows you to do layout customizations based on screen stat (like height/width)

Answer (score 0):

`So I need to be able to know how to calculate the viewport height because it's different`

Not really, you could use the [media query system](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to customize your layout to ANY browser (you know, except I.E.).

`I know that browser sniffing is not advisable`

Also depends on your applicatio. If you know an un-safe browser (you know, I.E.), you could want to not respond to that request.

`so what is one to do in a case like this? Ideas anyone? Have I misunderstood something?`

Apparently you have not misunderstood anything. However, there are more resources and guidelines that could help you with your problem.
You could fix your issue with the [onResize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onresize) function, and deal with changes yourself, use querys to fix the layout (I preffer using percentage based width/height changes) or even have separate pages, and use the User-Agent to change the result for the page

Comment: Unfortunately, media queries will not work in this case.

Comment: @fraxture Can you tell me why not? Are you not using a WebView? if so, then media query should work (it does on my testing devices, Sony, Samsumg and Motorolla)... Also, what about the onResize DOM function, does it not perform as expected?